# Showing that the space of bounded measurable functions can't be used to characterize convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

An exercise I am doing from Chung's book asks me to find some ***asbsolutely continuous*** probability measures $\mu_n, \mu$ and some measurable and bounded (but not continuous!) function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ \mu_n \rightarrow \mu$$

but such that

$$ \int f d\mu_n \not\to  \int f d\mu.$$

I am really stuck with this.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Gerald's answer in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131422/counterexample-of-non-negative-sequence-weakly-converging-in-mathscrm1-but gives what you want.